Error Loading ORC Files into BigQuery: "Invalid timestamp value" after 17th July 2024
I've been successfully fetching ORC files from an Azure Blob Storage to a GCS bucket using the Storage Transfer Service. This process handles around 100 files. After loading the files into GCS, I use Airflow's BashOperator with the bq load command to load them into BigQuery. Everything worked fine until 17th July 2024. However, since then, the workflow has been failing with the following error on a date field:
Error while reading data, error message: Invalid timestamp value (-62135769600 seconds, 0 nanoseconds)
I have verified with the source team, and they confirmed that there have been no changes on their end. The source data is from a SQL Server database. The data is exported from SQL Server using Azure Data Factory's Copy Activity to ORC files on Azure Blob Storage.
Error Details:
Error: Invalid timestamp value (-62135769600 seconds, 0 nanoseconds)
The issue started occurring on 17th July 2024.
What I've Tried:
Verified the data export process from SQL Server to ORC files via Azure Data Factory.It is working fil
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into why this timestamp error might be occurring? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

I would start by finding a tool that can extract a few rows of data from the ORC file.  Find what columns are the timestamp.  Use a tool to examine the values of the timestamp and list what you find.  Let's see what the ORC format believes the file contains and then we can see what BigQuery thinks is wrong with that.

Thanks Kolban . While doing that I found that I was getting createddate before 2022-12-10 16:48:38.045000 but Now I am getting 2022-12-10 16:48:38.0450000 .there is one 0 extra coming and that row it is throwing an error.
